# How to negative assert_response in unit testing with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, httpresponse

How can one test if the HTTP response is **not** something in the standard unit-testing framework with Rails (Ver 6.0, more specifically)? Basically it is negation of [assert_response](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions/assert_response) like this:

```rb
test "should get index" do
  get restricted_articles_url
  assert_response_NOT :success  # <= this method does not exist.
end
```

The background is, the user tested should not be granted access to the URL (or Controller method), but what response would be returned may change later in the development and the exact response is of secondary importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check the `response.code` directly with

```
# codes from 200 to 299 are :success
assert_not (200...299).include?(response.code.to_i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ref [rails-specific-assertions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.0/testing.html#rails-specific-assertions), Why don't you use the exact response which you are expecting instead of using negation of assert_response.

```
Asserts that the response comes with a specific status code. You can specify 
:success to indicate 200-299, :redirect to indicate 300-399, :missing to 
indicate 404, or :error to match the 500-599 range
```

For ex:-

```
 assert_response :redirect
```